# Running the script for the 2-nd time, the messages are not retrieved from the mail server

Tags: python, pop3

I read the mails from my gmail account with the code following below.

```
import poplib
pop_conn = poplib.POP3_SSL('pop.gmail.com')
pop_conn.user('user')             # result: '+OK send PASS'
pop_conn.pass_('password')        # result: '+OK Welcome.'
print pop_conn.list()[1]
pop_conn.quit()
```

It shows me 1 message as expected.
However, if I run this script for the second time, I get 0 messages as result. On the server the message is still there and unread.
How can I get all the messages also running the script for the second time?

For me it behaves as an email client that doesn't download the same mail twice. Is there some flag to force the program to download everything again?
I use python 2.7.x on ubuntu 12.10

Comment: maybe you can elaborate a bit, provide more context (e.g. which python version etc.).   The snippet showed works fine for me: I get same list of email messages each time.  I tried with python 2.7.x.

Comment: @mjv thanks for letting me know that it works on your PC. It's getting curioser and curioser. I use python 2.7.x on ubuntu 12.10

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that's all that you were doing when it happened? As far as I know, just using `list()` shouldn't do that, but if you used `retr()` to read the message contents too, then POP3 servers often mark the message and won't return it on further connections anymore.

You could try using IMAP instead, since it lets you specify the behavior in more detail, eg. you can tell it to not mark messages as seen and allows you to retrieve them more than once. Google supports IMAP and python has imaplib for using it.

Comment: after I failed with pop3, I made an imap solution that worked. I asked it here, in order to understand why it could fail. Now, I tried to run this script on the same machine and now it works each time that doesn't make it clear for me. I don't get it. At the time I posted the question, I might have tried retr(), but afterwards I did it several times: send the message, run the above snippet twice (and nothing in between), for the 1-st I got the message, for the 2-nd time - nothing. upvote from my side, but I'll wait with acceptation in case if somebody comes up with a 100% solution

Comment: Well that's certainly weird. In that case, I hope someone can think of a better explanation for this; now it bothers me too. :)